# Error with fopen() even though it is active in configuration

Tags: php

I have this code in my script:

```
$myFile = "1.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $sql);
fclose($fh);
```

And it show me can't open file !
Why is this error when allow_url_open is On in my php.ini configuration! I check this!

Comment: How is `$sql` being defined?

Comment: `allow_url_open` is irrelevant, `1.txt` is a local filesystem reference. Check directory/file permissions

Comment: $sql is: `$sql = "select * from adds where compain IN ($compainids) && publish='Yes' && type = '$type' order by rand()";`

Comment: I make permissions for folder where is located my file and now is work, thank you Mark!

Comment: Check to see if `1.txt` first exists, and that permissions are well set to write to the file. Your code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that `1.txt` already exists and that proper write permissions are set for both the file and the folder. Folders are usually set at `0755`.

You can do this via FTP using the `chmod` command, or implementing it in the code itself.

Try adding [`chmod`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) to your code:

```
$myFile = "1.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

chmod($myFile,0644);
fwrite($fh, $sql);
fclose($fh);
```

You can also try to change `0644` to `0777` but `0644` is a safer permission setting to use.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you dont have the permission to access the file from the directory.

You would need to give appropriate permission to the file using `chmod`.

You can see [chmod](http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/) permission rule here